# How to append and remove element after clone jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make like the following picture. Displays the delete button on the previous element and places the add button for the next element.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9m30.png)

I already made it, but I don't know how to add and delete at the same time.

```js
var btn_delete = '<button type="button" onclick="removeKolom($(this))">Delete</button>';

function removeKolom(e){
 e.parents('.kolom').remove();
}

function addElement(e) {
 $(".kolom:last").clone().appendTo(".data-repeater"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
   <th>Act</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="data-repeater">
  <tr class="kolom">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td class="btn-repeater">
     <button class="add-btn-repeat" onclick="addElement($(this))" type="button">Add</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would make far more sense to put the 'add' button outside of the table and then just have a 'delete' button on every row. You're making your code needlessly more complex, and the UI harder to understand for your users, but attempting to do it in the way you currently are.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But, i want make something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var btn_delete = '<button type="button" onclick="removeKolom($(this))">Delete</button>';
var btn_add = '<button class="add-btn-repeat" onclick="addElement($(this))" type="button">Add</button>';

function removeKolom(e) {
  e.parents('.kolom').remove();
}

function addElement(e) {
  var newElement = $(".kolom").first().clone();
  $(".kolom").find('button.add-btn-repeat').replaceWith(btn_delete);
  newElement.appendTo(".data-repeater").find('button').replaceWith(btn_add);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>Act</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="data-repeater">
    <tr class="kolom">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td class="btn-repeater">
        <button class="add-btn-repeat" onclick="addElement($(this))" type="button">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `addElement` function as following:

```
function addElement(e) {
   var $kolomLast = $(".kolom:last");
   $kolomLast.clone().appendTo(".data-repeater");
   $kolomLast.find(".add-btn-repeat").replaceWith(btn_delete);
}
```

You can keep a reference to the last row element and once it is cloned, you can change its button from `Add` to `Delete`.